# change dynamic border color in Action Script 3 by color picker

Tags: actionscript-3

here are code what i am doing but text border color not changed

```
 var txtFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); txtFormat.color = 0xAA0000; txtfc.setTextFormat(txtFormat);
```

I have added this code on a event by giving a different color value each time but text border color never changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var k:TextField = new TextField();
k.border = true;
k.borderColor = 0xff0000;
```

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt to address two different issues, as your question text and accompanying code are somewhat incongruous.

It appears that you are attempting to change the color of the text.

Your code is mostly correct, but you'll want to change the line `txtfc.setTextFormat(txtFormat);` to `txtfc.defaultTextFormat = txtFormat;` This will ensure that the change you made to `txtFormat` will affect the entire text field.

Otherwise, please see @Pan's response on how to set the border color of the text field by settings the `border` property to `true` and settings the `borderColor` property as needed.